# Returning and consuming json in webservice

Tags: json, web-services, rest

I'm trying to move my jax-rs webservice from XML to JSON. I have created the classes using JAXB. I'm using the Jackson 1.x jars.

The XML request to the webservice used to be like

```
<authenticateUser>
    <userName>M</userName>
    <userPassword>P</userPassword>
</authenticateUser>
```

but after converting to Json, the service expects the request like

```
{ 
 "userName":"M",
 "userPassword":"P"
}
```

Shouldn't the json string be wrapped in the `authenticateUser`, like the xml?

The resource class the signature is like

```
public Response authenticate(AuthenticateUser authenticateUser){
     // Code goes in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. In XML, the root of your object is `<authenticateUser>`, but in JSON you cannot name the root, so it's simply `{`.

In JavaScript, it would be written like this:

```
var authenticateUser = { 
    "userName":"M",
    "userPassword":"P"
}
```